# C# SerialPort DataReceived Event not updating main UI

Tags: c#, delegates, serial-port, multithreading

I'm presently working on a burglar alarm solution having coded it entirely in c#. The program talks to a USB serial port based based IO board which has the alarm sensors hardwired into it. I'm having an issue whereby the DataReceived event is not able to update the main UI unless I call a sub called TextLog (see end) from within the DataReceived event. Oddly enough, the DataReceived event from querying Zone 1 is able to update the main UI but not Zone 2 or 3. Additionally, if I insert a break point at the line where the Serial Port write is performed, it works as expected.

Worth mentioning these global variables:

```
string ioCardRxString = "";

bool[] arrGlobalZoneStatus = new bool[4];
```

Open the serial port by reading settings from the Settings file (all works well).

```
private void OpenIOComPort()
    {
        bool error = false;

        else
        {
            // Set the port's settings
            spIOCard.PortName = Settings1.Default.ioComPort;
            spIOCard.BaudRate = int.Parse(Settings1.Default.ioBaudRate);
            spIOCard.DataBits = int.Parse(Settings1.Default.ioDataBits);
            spIOCard.StopBits = (System.IO.Ports.StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(System.IO.Ports.StopBits), Settings1.Default.ioStopBits);
            spIOCard.Parity = (System.IO.Ports.Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(System.IO.Ports.Parity), Settings1.Default.ioParity);
            spIOCard.Handshake = (System.IO.Ports.Handshake)Enum.Parse(typeof(System.IO.Ports.Handshake), Settings1.Default.ioHandshake);

            try
            {
                // Open the port
                spIOCard.Open();
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { error = true; }
            catch (System.IO.IOException) { error = true; }
            catch (ArgumentException) { error = true; }

            //On error, advise the user
            if (error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Could not open the I/O Board COM port.");                    
                globalIOCardError = true;
            }

            if (!error)
            {
                globalIOCardError = false;
                // Do Nothing
            }

        }
    }
```

A timer runs every 500ms, it writes 3 commands to the serial port, each separated by 25ms (hardware limitation). These commands query the IO board in order to determine the status of each alarm sensor.

```
private void tmrAuditSensors_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        try
        {
            if (globalIOCardError == false && Settings1.Default.disableSensorAudit == false)
            {
                if (Settings1.Default.zone1Armed == true)
                {
                    spIOCard.Write("~in01~");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(25);;
                }

                if (Settings1.Default.zone2Armed == true)
                {
                    spIOCard.Write("~in02~");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(25);;
                }

                if (Settings1.Default.zone3Armed == true)
                {
                    spIOCard.Write("~in03~");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(25);;
                }

                //Applicable results will appear on serial data received event
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            textLog("There was a problem writing to the serial port, check and restart app");
            emergencyHalt();
        }
    }
```

The Serial Port DataReceived event reads the returned string and writes to a global array of booleans. True if that zone is open (=1), and False if it is closed (=0). NOTE: the starred line.

```
private void spIO_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        ioCardRxString = spIOCard.ReadExisting();
        textLog(ioCardRxString); //*Cannot make it work without this

        if (ioCardRxString.Contains("in05=1") == true)
        {
            arrGlobalZoneStatus[1] = true;
        }

        if (ioCardRxString.Contains("in05=0") == true)
        {
            arrGlobalZoneStatus[1] = false;
        }

        if (ioCardRxString.Contains("in01=1") == true)
        {
            arrGlobalZoneStatus[2] = true;
        }

        if (ioCardRxString.Contains("in01=0") == true)
        {
            arrGlobalZoneStatus[2] = false;
        }

        if (ioCardRxString.Contains("in17=1") == true)
        {
            arrGlobalZoneStatus[3] = true;
        }

        if (ioCardRxString.Contains("in17=0") == true)
        {
            arrGlobalZoneStatus[3] = false;
        }

    }
```

Separately, another timer periodically (every 250ms) checks the contents of each array member and then accordingly updates the main UI with some colour changing and text updates.

```
 private void tmrCheckZoneStatus_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (arrGlobalZoneStatus[1] == true)
        {
            button10.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            textLog(button10.Text + " was activated");

            if (globalFullAlarmSet || globalNightAlarmSet || globalDoorsAlarmSet)
            {
                this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(delegate { checkAndActivateRelays(1); }));
            }
        }

        if (arrGlobalZoneStatus[1] == false)
        {
            button10.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
        }

        if (arrGlobalZoneStatus[2] == true)
        {
            button11.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            textLog(button11.Text + " was activated"); ;

            if (globalFullAlarmSet || globalNightAlarmSet || globalDoorsAlarmSet)
            {
                this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(delegate { checkAndActivateRelays(2); }));
            }
        }

        if (arrGlobalZoneStatus[2] == false)
        {
            button11.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
        }

        if (arrGlobalZoneStatus[3] == true)
        {
            button12.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            textLog(button12.Text + " was activated");

            if (globalFullAlarmSet || globalNightAlarmSet || globalDoorsAlarmSet)
            {
                this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(delegate { checkAndActivateRelays(3); }));
            }
        }

        if (arrGlobalZoneStatus[3] == false)
        {
            button12.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
        }

    }
```

textLog sub:

```
public void textLog(string logEntry)
    {
        textLines++;
        try
        {
            if (this.txtLog.InvokeRequired)
            {
                ChangeTextCallback MethodCallback = new ChangeTextCallback(textLog);
                this.Invoke(MethodCallback, new object[] { logEntry });
            }
            else
            {
                if (!logEntry.Contains("?"))
                {
                    txtLog.Text = txtLog.Text + DateTime.Now + " >: " + logEntry + "\r\n";
                    txtLog.SelectionStart = txtLog.Text.Length;
                    txtLog.ScrollToCaret();

                    if (textLines > 3000)
                    {
                        txtLog.Clear();
                        textLines = 0;
                        textLog("Text log cleared");
                    }

                    System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(logFile, true);
                    try
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " >: " + logEntry);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //
                    }

                    sw.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //
        }


    }
```

I guess I need to incorporate invoke/delegate somewhere but as a noob I'm kind of scratching my head. Your help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not trying to sound like a jerk, but we don't care about all the intricate details on your system. Can you please simplify the problem, and show just the minimal code and details that exemplify the issue you're having?

Answer (score 3):

I didn't read throuh everything, but this should get you going on the right path:

The [`SerialPort.DataReceived`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx) event is raised on a separate thread.  If you need to asynchronously handle the receipt of data, and do something with the GUI on it, you would do something like this:

```
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {
    var port = (SerialPort)sender;
    string data = port.ReadExisting();

    UpdateGui(data);
}

private void UpdateGui(string data) {
    if (this.InvokeRequired) {
        this.Invoke(new Action( d => UpdateGui(d) ));
        return;
    }

    this.txtBox1.Text = data;
}
```

Now, that said.... *Do you really want to be using `DataReceived`?*  It sounds like you (the host computer) is initiating all communication with the external board.  If that is the case, then I recommend you use Synchronous (blocking) reads instead:

```
1. Write the request out the port
2. Call read() with the expected number of bytes
3. Process the reply.
```

Comment: Indeed; DataReceived will notify you immediately once the serial port buffer contains some bytes, but they might be incomplete messages and you might end up with missed messages. If the hardware offers some separators between what it outputs, I suggest you read until you encounter those in order to make sure you're processing complete messages. This should simplify things and save you from asynchronous headaches.